# Need to convert date in format of "MM/dd/yy" to epoch in R

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a data frame with dates in the human readable format "MM/dd/yy" to epoch days.

Here is an example of the data frame:

```
    human.date
    1    7/25/11
    2    7/25/11
    3    7/25/11
    4    7/25/11         
    5    7/25/11
    6    7/25/11
```

I want to utilize this function to convert each date in the data frame to epoch days:

```
# Convert from human readable date to days since epoch and round to nearest day
round(as.numeric(as.POSIXct("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", origin="1970-01-01"))/86400)
```

However, the function above only works if the human readable date is in the format of "yyyy/MM/dd".

```
round(as.numeric(as.POSIXlt("2000/02/20", origin="1970-01-01"))/86400)
[1] 11007
```

Is there an easier way to do this conversion or another function I can use that will take dates in the format of "MM/dd/yy"?

Comment: What are epoch days?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `format` argument of the `as.POSIXlt` function:

```
> human.date <- "7/25/11"
> round(as.numeric(as.POSIXlt(human.date, format = "%M/%d/%y", origin = "1970-01-01"))/86400)
[1] 15180
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know how I would also iterate through an entire data frame with about 600+ dates and apply that function?

Comment: Take a look at the `dplyr` package, and the `mutate` function in particular